# What is the Linux command to get the current PPTP ip address?

Tags: networking, bash

I have a Linux script that allows me to route some traffic through a VPN interface, and other traffic (from different IP) through another interface.
This is my script:

```
echo "ip route del default via 192.168.120.10 dev ppp0;" >> /tmp/firewallscript.sh
echo "ip route add default via 192.168.1.254 dev eth0;" >> /tmp/firewallscript.sh
echo "ip route add table 55 default via 192.168.120.10 dev ppp0;" >> /tmp/firewallscript.sh
echo "iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING 1 -s 192.168.1.40 -j MARK --set-mark 55;" >> /tmp/firewallscript.sh
echo "iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING 1 -s 192.168.1.41 -j MARK --set-mark 55;" >> /tmp/firewallscript.sh
echo "iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING 1 -s 192.168.1.42 -j MARK --set-mark 55;" >> /tmp/firewallscript.sh
echo "ip rule add fwmark 55 table 55;" >> /tmp/firewallscript.sh
```

Because my VPN's IP changes a lot, I would like to 'parametrize' it. 
So instead of write this line code:

```
echo "ip route del default via 192.168.120.10 dev ppp0;" >> /tmp/firewallscript.sh
```

I need to write something like:

```
echo "ip route del default via @MyVariableIP dev ppp0;" >> /tmp/firewallscript.sh
```

In which @MyVariableIP  is ppp0's IP address. 
So my questions are:

1. How can I get interface IP address using bash, knowing that the interface is ppp0?
2. How to modify the previous script?

Thanks

Comment: `ip addr show dev ppp0` will show you the current IP address(es) of *ppp0*.

Comment: @scai That would make a fine answer.

Comment: unfortunately, ip addr show not working in dd-wrt busy box ! Argh! Any alternative ?

Comment: Does `ifconfig` work? You can slice & dice its output using `grep`, `awk`, and `sed`. Then capture the result into a variable, and use that variable inside the strings.

Answer (score 0):

1. At the end of this script you can get ip of ppp0 in $ip_of_ppp0 variable
2. Put this script before yours and replace @MyVariableIP with $ip_of_ppp0

   ```
   n=`ifconfig|grep -B10 'POINTOPOINT' | cut -d " " -f1 `
   m=`ifconfig|grep -B8 'POINTOPOINT'|cut -d " " -f12|grep 'addr:1'|cut -d ":" -f2 `
   f=`echo $n`
   l=`echo $m`
   arr=($f)
   amm=($l)
   h=0
   for i in "${arr[@]}"; do              
           ip=${amm[$h]}
           h=`expr $h+1`
           if [[ "$i" = "ppp0" ]]; then
                   ip_of_ppp0=$ip;
           fi    
   done
   echo $ip_of_ppp0;
   ```